# "ubuntu-desktop" disappear on reboot (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: boot, crash, .desktop

Situation now: every time I reboot, I'm having to reinstall "ubuntu-desktop" because its not available on startup.

On boot, it goes to "tty1", if I try going to 7/8 it just shows a blinking underscore. Control Alt Del makes it reboot from there.

The only weird thing is that before that, there was a popup for "partial upgrade", I clicked continue, it downloaded and installed a bunch of stuff, I shut down the computer, came back a few hours later, and this.

A few times, it would crash back to the blinking underscore a few minutes into the session. Right now, it's stable, but on booting, it lose everything again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue today on Ubuntu 22.04.3. Fixed it by:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

On my end, some of the drivers were also broken by the failed upgrade, so I fixed that issue with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Looks like the issue is caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)

Comment: i think I had to keep reinstalling because one of the things I found recommended dist-upgrade... which removed things again...