# My 22.04.3 LTS starts in console mode

Tags: boot, command-line, gui

IAC: Earlier today, I noticed an "icon" (do not enter) which when "hit" told me I had some broken packages. I followed along - and started a package update process.

I left the room for a bit, and upon my return there was a blinking cursor on the screen. After waiting a few minutes to see if it was "working" on something, I decided something untoward had happened. So, I rebooted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>).

It came up in console mode. I rebooted to recovery mode then I ran `dpkg` and `clean` - the latter took some time...

It still starts in console mode.

Any help to get a GUI going would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ubuntu-desktop" disappear on reboot (Ubuntu 22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481221/ubuntu-desktop-disappear-on-reboot-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Thank you sotirov: sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop worked. After running that, I reinstalled an nvidia driver. Alles goot! I think this issue was caused by my thinking a blinking cursor, after starting a package update, meant the machine had given up the ghost.  When I booted into recovery mode and ran dpkg and clean, I saw a lot of "font files" (and a lot of other files) removed . When I reinstalled ubuntu desktop, I saw a lot of font files, etc. installed. Lesson learned: A blinking cursor needs to be given a few minutes.

Comment: Yes, it answers my question. Is there a way for me to acknowledge the solution?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to wait a few minutes when a cursor is blinking. But in this case, It's a bug, not you fault. Some people waited the blinking cursor for hours and nothing happened.

Comment: I am happy that it solved your problem. I have no idea how you can mark my comment as the solution. I marked you question as duplicate to the other issue where I have responded, so if you want, you can upvote my answer there. There are a least 6 more  questions similar to yours.

Comment: I saw those previous posts, but I recall the most recent (that I saw) was a few years old. And I don't know if solutions to similar problems change. I don't want to use solutions that might lead to more problems. I will have a look to see if I can figure out how to upvote you. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I did not see the recent post that you also responded - and also referred me to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)

Fixed it by:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

On my end, some of the drivers were also broken by the failed upgrade, so I fixed that issue with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```