# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS won't power off

Tags: kernel, graphics, shutdown, reboot

I am having problems with shutting down Ubuntu for the last one or two days now. My device is set on dual boot. I don't have this problem with Windows 11. I tried
-acpi=force, &,
-update grab, upgrade grab
etc.
My device is an Acer Nitro 5 with Intel i5 11400H and Nvidia geforce rtx 3050
The kernel is 6.2.0-26-generic
My graphics in Ubuntu is being displayed as mesa intel UHD graphics(TGL GT1).

[image: It gets stuck at this point.]

The same thing happens with restart. It also doesn't start after being put to sleep. It doesn't have any problems during starting.
Windows isn't giving me any issues.

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481221/ubuntu-desktop-disappear-on-reboot-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: It seems like a problem with the new video driver nouveau it can be fixed using a patch https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-6.2/+bug/2031352

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I experienced a similar issue: my computer was not restarting or powering off properly. The only way to restart was to hold down Alt+PrtScreen keys while typing R E I S U B. And the only way to power it off was by holding down the power button for a few seconds.

My computer is an Alienware Alienware m15 R7, graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits) / Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2), OS Name Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, only with Ubuntu (no Windows, no dual-boot).

The kernel running while the problem was happening was *6.2.0-26-generic*.

I happened to have run `echo "$(uname -r)"` before the poweroff issue, and found then that the kernel running was *5.19.0-50-generic*. So I downgraded the kernel to 5.19.0-50-generic and removed 6.2.0-26-generic following this guide https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/ and now restart and poweroff functions are working properly again.

The ideal solution will be when the latest kernel gets fixed. While the kernel is fixed, downgrading worked fine here.

Comment: Yes it seems many user have had issues with upgrading to 22.04.3 and kernel 6.2.

Comment: Thanks! I could solve the issue by using another kernel at the boot menu