# Update August 5 2023 now no gui,and quite lost

Tags: boot

Cannot boot to gui since Aug 5 2023 update.

I expected the usual process but? I have seen other posts very similar but no joy.
Hardware is Lenovo H530 for many years and Intel SSD.
OS is Ubuntu 22.04.
Machine boots to $, no wifi access. I have a 22.04 live USB that works fine but I am unsure about use.

Comment: The $ is probably a root prompt.  try dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop

Comment: One way to fix is to chroot to the installation using the live USB (which is connected to the internet) and run the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ubuntu-desktop" disappear on reboot (Ubuntu 22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481221/ubuntu-desktop-disappear-on-reboot-ubuntu-22-04)